# Mono-based Firefox Add-on?

Tags: .net, mono, firefox-addon

Anyone tried to use Mono to write a Firefox Addon yet?  Did it work cross-platform (Linux/Windows)?

Perhaps the Moonlight Add-on for Firefox is a good model?

Answer (score 3):

I've not tried it, but I suspect you'd need some kind of shim at the very least. Native code that would be able to load the Mono runtime into the process so that an assembly could be loaded.